# How to read a number on specific column and line in Python?

Tags: python

Sorry I don't have much experience with Python.

I have a text file containing 10 lines. First 3 lines have 3 columns and next 7 lines have 4 columns.

I need to read three number from the first three lines each of them are stored in different column:

For example my file looks like this:

```
25 0 0
0 47 0
0 0 89
1 4 6 10
12 5 2 0
2 0 12 3
12 0 2 0
0 0 12 0
1 3 5 19
0 0 0 20
```

I need to a Python script to read the three numbers first (Line 1 column 1)
second (Line 2 column 2) third (line 3 column 3) and stores it in an (1,3) array.

So the three numbers which needs to be read from example above will be:

```
25
47
89
```

which needs to be stored in an array.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try to write code? Can you show some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will take all the diagonals from (0,0) up to the count in the xrange and store them in the list `out`. For the above example I've made the xrange from 0-2 so it will give the 3 numbers required.

```
out = []
f = open('test.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
for i in xrange(0,3):
    out.append(f[i].split()[i])
```

Comment: It is perfect thank you. If the numbers were not on diagonal how could I read those?

Comment: Well if you see what `f[i].split()[i]` is doing then you'll see that you can just replace the `i` with numbers corresponding to the numbers in your array. For example, if you wanted the 3rd number in the 5th column you'd do `f[4].split()[2]` (subtract 1 from the indexing because it's a zero-indexed array)

Comment: Thanks so much. I will spend some time to learn Python. but currently I am very bad at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of a file into an array, e.g. by doing the following

```
    f = open('somefile.txt',"r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Each entry in the list "lines" is one line of the file as a string. Strings can be split by a deliminator using the inbuilt function [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm).

Then it is just a matter of selecting the 3rd or the 4th entry.

If you post what you have tried, then you will get more concrete feedback.